# write data into the text output file

Tags: matlab, printf

I have input.dat like that:

```
1  1  1  2  3  10  17  16 15 8  9
2  1  3  4  5  12  19  18 17 10 11
3  1  5  6  7  4   21  20 19 12 13
4  1  15 16 17 24  31  30 29 22 23
```

1st column : numel
2nd column : matno
3rd-12st column : lnods

I wrote as follow;

```
fprintf(FID6,'N  PRO     POINTS \n');

MATNO=zeros(4,1);
LNODS=zeros(4,9);

 for IELEM=1:NELEM

 NUMEL(IELEM,:)=fscanf(FID5, '%d', 1);
 MATNO(IELEM,:)=fscanf(FID5, '%d', 1);
 LNODS(IELEM,:)=fscanf(FID5, '%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d',[9,1]);

  end

  fprintf(FID6, '%-2d           %-2d        %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-      2d\n',NUMEL,MATNO,LNODS);
```

I expect:

```
N  PRO    　　           POINTS
1　  1　 　　1   2   3   10   17   16   15   8   9 
2　  1　 　　3   4   5   12   19   18   17   10  11
3　  1　 　　5   6   7   4    21   20   19   12  13
4　  1　 　　15   16  17  24   31   30   29   22  23
```

but

```
N  PRO    　　           POINTS
1　  2　 　　3   4   1   1   1   1   1  3   5
15　 2　 　　4   6   16  ...
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I didn't write that. NELEM=9

Answer (score 0):

Use **tabs** instead of plain spaces. Much cleaner.

For example:

```
fprintf(FID6, '%-2d\t%-2d\t%-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d\n',NUMEL,MATNO,LNODS);
```

And also spacing, why put %-2d? try %4d or something and remove whitespaces

```
fprintf(FID6,'%4d\t%4d\t%4d%4d%4d%4d%4d%4d%4d%4d%4d\n',NUMEL,MATNO,LNODS)
```

Comment: Thank you but I mean,i want to NUMEL AND MATNO print out in column direction.

Comment: oh! I'm sorry I didn't notice that. Was the edited output the actual problem or something went missing?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understanding your answer. I checked debugging stage, the size of NUMEL, MATNO and LNODS and value is that i expected. however, output text file is not. I can't catch the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a usual pitfall when trying to use `fprintf` for writing matrices to a file. `fprintf`  serializes the data column-wise and not row-wise like you want.

The simplest solution in your case is to add a `for` loop just like you did with the input:

```
for k = 1:numel(NUMEL)
    fprintf(FID6, '%-2d\t%-2d\t%-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d\n', NUMEL(k), MATNO(k), LNODS(k, :));
end
```

Alternatively, you can create one large matrix from your values and pass *its transpose* to `fprintf`:

```
A = [NUMEL, MATNO, LNODS].';  %// Note the transpose operator .'
fprintf(FID6, '%-2d\t%-2d\t%-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d\n', A);
```

I usually prefer the latter solution because it doesn't involve explicit loops.